# Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in Magento Enterprise 1.14

Tags: magento

Getting this error

```
Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php on line 611
```

Code on line 611

> if (!empty(self::$_regexMatchCache[$rule['regexp']][$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']]))

when web service call from mobile app is done. After some research i got that in Package.php file need to check HTTP_USER_AGENT where it's having if condition also  found that in System > Configuration >Design we can add exception to change theme for mobile which in my case is blank, is this case i am getting this error or some thing else?

Comment: How does line 611 look like?